# behaviour of async/await functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am seeing an unexpected output when running some functions using async/await which I can't work out.

The code looks like:

```js
const delayToRun = async() => {
  console.log('first delay');
  let p = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('Done'), 2000);
  });
  console.log('second delay');
  return p;
};

const start = async() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    const res = await delayToRun();
    console.log(res);
    console.log('--------------------------------');
  }
};

start();
start();
```

Output:

```txt
first delay
first delay
second delay
Done
--------------------------------
first delay
second delay
Done
--------------------------------
first delay
second delay
Done
--------------------------------
second delay
Done
--------------------------------
```

For me it would make sense that all blocks display: first, second, Done.
But the first one seems to start at the beginning then complete at the end.

Can someone shed some light on this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not `await`-ing your `start()` function, so the second instance of `start()` is triggered immediately after the first one.

For comparison:

```js
delayToRun = async() => {
  console.log("first delay");
  let p = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Done"), 2000)
  });
  console.log("second delay");
  return p;
}

start = async() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    const res = await delayToRun();
    console.log(res);
    console.log("--------------------------------");
  }
}

(async () => {
  await start();
  await start();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running `start()` twice, independently, concurrently, since they don't wait for each other. It might help to understand the behaviour by printing the source of each log line to better distinguish them:

```js
async function delayToRun(source) {
  console.log(`${source} before delay`);
  const done = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Done"), 200);
  });
  console.log(`${source} after delay`);
  return done;
};

async function start(source) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    const res = await delayToRun(`${source}, i=${i}`);
    console.log(`${source}, i=${i}: ${res}`);
  }
};

start("task=1");
start("task=2");
```

> But the first one seems to start at the beginning then complete at the end.

From the output, you can see that actually they execute in lockstep.